# Add and Remove transparent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have added a transparent div on a window(with treeview) as follows in a function :

```
function add()
{
$dialog.html('<div id="div1"  style="background: url(img/trans.png); opacity:0.1; filter:alpha(opacity=10); "></div>');
}
```

How do I remove this div so that I can see the contents of the window again in another function.

Comment: Are you looking for `$dialog.empty()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#div1', $dialog).remove();
```

It'll remove the `div` which id's `#div1` from the `$dialog`.

If you use `$dialog.html()` you'll overwrite the html content, so try to use `append` if you want to get it back.

Look this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LXtF9/1/).

**References**:
   ***jQuery.remove()***: http://api.jquery.com/remove/
***jQuery.append()***: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: when I am using append, it adds the content below the current contents of the window whereas I want it from the top of the window at the start. is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
function subtract(){
$dialog.html('');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It removes the div but I cannot see the original window content.

Comment: is there any html in the object 'dialog' before you call the function add?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to "hide" *div1*:

```
$("#div1").css("display","none");
```

Comment: Thanks. It removes the div but I cannot see the original window content.

Comment: I want the window content back to be seen.